# Microsoft TFS Rest API for repository list does not return ssh URLs

Tags: rest, tfs

[image: TFS Rest API]

TFS server version: 2017
Compatible API version <= 3.0
The Rest API endpoint to fetch the information for tfs-git repositories is mentioned here:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1]

This returns the HTTP clone links for the repositories but not the ssh URL. Also, the documentation does not mention any API option to get the same.

Is there for API not including the ssh URLs?

Again, **this isn't visual studio but TFS server.**

Answer (score 0):

Are sure this is the case, as if I call. 
https://dev.azure.com/PeterLai0838/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1

i get

"remoteUrl":"https://PeterLai0838@dev.azure.com/PeterLai0838/roboops/_git/roboops",
"sshUrl":"git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/PeterLai0838/roboops/roboops",
"webUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/PeterLai0838/roboops/_git/roboops"}]

Ah wait, i notice your using the 4.1 api, maybe use the 5.1?

Comment: Exactly! we do get ssh URLs for Azure DevOps services/server using the new API versions. But this is not the case for TFS enterprise server. TFS server v2017 supports API version between v1 to v3.

Comment: Hmmm, prob not supported then, you could re-arragen the https url yourself and create the ssh one, it won't be 100% but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the option left then. It's hard to understand why Microsoft no longer provides the Rest API documentation for old TFS versions!

Comment: maybe worth download the old version and seeing if they shipped it with the api docs? you might get lucky. Or check the install folder of your install in your case.

Comment: It may not have been a stable public API at the time 2017 was released. The SSH protocol was added around that time. This API was probably in preview at the time and that's why it wasn't documented at that version. Only the latest preview and final versions are documented on the docs site.

Answer (score 0):

sshURL is supported in TFS 2018 and later. You may submit a feature request at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22